# How to reset graphic drivers from command line

Tags: release-freya, graphic-drivers, nvidia

I am using elementary OS Freya and tried to install some graphic drivers and update existing drivers, after the re-start I get black screen, but still I can access command line from recovery mode, how can I re-set my graphic drivers ?

Comment: This link might be helpful for NVIDIA gpu: http://askubuntu.com/questions/41681/blank-screen-after-installing-nvidia-restricted-driver

Comment: I just re install the "xserver-xorg-video-nouveau" and it works fine but OS automatically download some OpenGL related packages and after the re-start the desktop seems like broken, https://www.dropbox.com/s/c4cn334andjxo8e/WP_20151220_22_02_02_Pro.jpg?dl=0  https://www.dropbox.com/s/wjg6n4prg5h8xoi/WP_20151220_22_02_10_Pro.jpg?dl=0

Comment: How do you install your graphic driver? If I had this problem on my PC with Nvidia, I just type the sudo apt-get purge nvidia*, and everything comes back after this.

Comment: Remove new drivers and reinstall needed driver via apt

Answer (score 10):

Thanks to [@cl-netbox](https://askubuntu.com/users/260935/cl-netbox) for instructions/assistance.

---

You did not provide any details about the hardware (desktop PC or notebook), especially about the GPU.
But you mentioned in your comment below `xserver-xorg-video-nouveau`, so I *assume* you have a NVIDIA GPU. 
 I will give you a comprehensive answer which should address nearly every possibility to solve your problem.

---

NVIDIA provides different versions of graphics drivers.

The current stable drivers are distributed through  the official repositories.
The latest official drivers are distributed through the Proprietary GPU Drivers PPA.

Generally you should use the drivers from the official repositories.
When you have issues with these drivers, you can install the drivers from the GPU Drivers PPA.

This often leads to properly working graphics, especially on very new NVIDIA GEFORCE adapters.

---

**Step 1** : Remove NVIDIA drivers you have installed

Open a terminal and execute :

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia*
sudo reboot
```

**Step 2** : Identify the exact graphics adapter model

Open a terminal and execute :

```
lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D'
```

**Step 3**: (Re)install NVIDIA drivers to the system

For NVIDIA GEFORCE 400 - 700 I recommend to install NVIDIA drivers version 352.

Open a terminal and execute :

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-352
sudo reboot
```

For NVIDIA GEFORCE 800 - 900 I recommend to install NVIDIA drivers version 358.

Open a terminal and execute :

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-358
sudo reboot
```

---

In case you experience a black screen, perform everything from a *virtual console.*
Highlight the elementary OS entry in the GRUB boot menu and press the <kbd>E</kbd> key.
Add `nouveau.modeset=0` to the end of the linux line and then press <kbd>F10</kbd> to boot.
On the login screen press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd>   and enter user name and password.
Now execute the commands ...