# elementary OS 0.3.2 Freya (64-bit) (Ubuntu 14.04) black screen after Update

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics

Hello I have a problem with ubuntu installed on my laptop.

The laptop is ASUS K501U with NVIDIA Corporation GM107M [GeForce GTX 950M] (rev a2). My System is elementary OS 0.3.2 Freya (64-bit).

The problem is after I installed updates to my system my graphic card drivers broke. When I turn on the computer I get black screen after selecting the system ( I have ubuntu and windows installed) I think that it is working because I can hear the login screen sound.

What I found was : https://askubuntu.com/questions/41681/blank-screen-after-installing-nvidia-restricted-driver

But it only displays the screen with 1024x764 resolution

I found that I can install other drivers from software updates. But selecting e.g nvidia 375.20, which is recommened for this graphic card breaks the display again ( black after rebooting ) and I have to repeat to process from the link above once again and use low resolution.

I also tried this link: https://askubuntu.com/questions/684181/asus-strix-gtx970-unable-to-get-1920x1080-resolution-ubuntu-14-04

But nothing changed, still black screen after reboot.

Please help :(

Comment: Hope it gives you some orientation: http://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/a/3729/6398

Comment: My recommendation is that you update to elementary OS Loki. My second recommendation is that you check what graphics drivers you have avaliable `sudo ubuntu-drivers devices | grep -o nvidia-[[:digit:]]* ` and install the previous one (not the 375). Also, updating your drivers directly from the Nvidia site is NEVER a good idea.

Comment: I solved My problem by installing Ubuntu 16.04.

Answer (score 1):

It may be due to kernel issues. Try to boot with an older kernel from grub menu as below.

- Select Advanced options for elementary os
- Select the kernel which u think is suitable

If that works, you can remove the new kernel while retaining the older one. But be sure to check which kernel u currently using by

> uname -r

and try not mess with it.

To remove kernel, replace X.XX.X-XX with kernel version as below

> sudo apt purge linux-image-X.XX.X-XX-generic linux-image-extra-X.XX.X-X-generic linux-headers-X.XX.X-XX linux-headers-X.XX.X-XX-generic

Then update the grub

> sudo update-grub

Reboot ur system.

Comment: Maybe include Ukuu as an alternative method of managing kernels. Also the kernel version is mentioned in the Settings > About screen.