# How to install nvidia graphics driver for nvidia 820m on loki?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics

Im new to elementary os andi want to know how to best install nvidia graphics driver  for  the above model (i used 364.51 for windows 10 ) on loki

Comment: You can get a nice Answer here: http://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/a/3729/6398

Comment: Don't do that. That question is a bit outdated.

Comment: You're right @Maccer your answer provides a better solution.

Answer (score 2):

First, check what drivers are avaliable for your system:

```
sudo ubuntu-drivers devices | grep -o nvidia-[[:digit:]]*
```

Then install the one you want (replace XXX with the correct number):

```
sudo apt install nvidia-XXX
```

In case you have Optimus Technology you would also want to install this:

```
sudo apt install nvidia-prime
```

In case you want to fine tune your settings, is recommended to install `nvidia-settings` as well:

```
sudo apt install nvidia-settings
```