# Nvidia drivers for Loki on an optimus system do not seem to work

Tags: graphic-drivers, nvidia, laptop

I followed the instructions here [How to install nvidia graphics driver for nvidia 820m on loki?](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/9605/how-to-install-nvidia-graphics-driver-for-nvidia-820m-on-loki/9609#9609) however if I run

```
sudo prime-select nvidia
glxgears
```

I get

```
X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range for    operation)
  Major opcode of failed request:  155 (GLX)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  3 (X_GLXCreateContext)
  Value in failed request:  0x0
  Serial number of failed request:  23
  Current serial number in output stream:  24
```

I'm using a dell xps 15z and `lspci | grep 'VGA\|3D'`outputs

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 06)
02:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK107M [GeForce GT 750M] (rev a1)
```

I've been trying different things for a while and am stumped.

Comment: Try the instructions in this answer instead: https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/a/3729/26

Answer (score 0):

The problem was actually something obvious.  I failed to turn off secure boot correctly.  I always thought it was odd that I never seemed to have to enter the password I set, not realizing I was passing over the spot to do it while booting.  The windows was so small on my screen to barely be legible.  When I did enter the password instead of pressing enter and passing over the prompt the drivers worked.